# Maple like simple plot in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, maple

The following graphic is from *Maple*

[image]

How to make a same graphic by using *Mathematica*

I tried:

```
ListPlot[{Table[EulerPhi[n], {n, 2, 40}], 
Table[PrimePi[n], {n, 2, 40}]}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
Filling -> Bottom, AxesStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> 0.45]
```

[image]

How to make background horizontal black lines, and same `Filling` lines?

Comment: `FillingStyle` and `GridLInes`.  It's all there.

Comment: `FillingStyle -> Dotted, GridLines -> {None, Range[10, 30, 10]}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the original `Plot` the x values are slightly offset from the integer values so that the markers and filling lines do not completely overlap. Also, the `AxesOrigin` is slightly shifted.

**EDIT:** Added [`PlotMarkers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html) option

```
offset = 0.1;

ListPlot[{
  Table[{n - offset, EulerPhi[n]}, {n, 2, 40}],
  Table[{n + offset, PrimePi[n]}, {n, 2, 40}]},
 GridLines -> {None, Range[10, 30, 10]},
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red},
 PlotMarkers -> {●, ◆},
 PlotRange -> {{1.5, 40.5}, Automatic},
 Filling -> Bottom,
 FillingStyle -> Dotted,
 AspectRatio -> 0.5,
 ImageSize -> 400,
 AxesOrigin -> {1.5, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hanson How Can I change red circle to red rhombus?

Comment: @vito - see edit